# How to access constant defined outside class?

Tags: php, class, constants, global

I have defined some constants eg:

```
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost', true);
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root', true);
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root', true);
define('DB_DATABASE', 'authtest', true);
```

now when I try to do this:

```
class Auth{
function AuthClass() {
$this->db_link = mysql_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) 
or die(mysql_error());
}
}
```

I get an error. **Why is this and what do I need to do?**

See, I've tried using (for example) `global DB_HOSTNAME` but this fails with an error.

The error I am getting is:

> **Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOSTNAME' (1)**

Comment: If you're getting that error, the define definitely isn't defined when the method is invoked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the script runs, both the constant and the class definitions should be included.

e.g.

constants.php.inc

```
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost', true);
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root', true);
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root', true);
define('DB_DATABASE', 'authtest', true);
```

Auth.php.inc

```
class Auth{
    function AuthClass() {
        $this->db_link = mysql_connect(DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD) 
           or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

script.php

```
include "constants.php.inc";
include "Auth.php.inc";

//do stuff
```

Comment: Umm.  That really doesn't do anything to address the issue since classes do not recognize variables set outside the scope of the class. All this does is reorganize the information with exactly the same result.

Comment: @Joseph Constants aren't variables, and they are indeed recognized inside any function/method that is executed after they are defined.  This is a valid answer and may indeed answer the question.

Comment: the above answer is the problem I have

Comment: @Ashley Ward see here http://codepad.viper-7.com/WcDT6R As you can see, you can access defined define's inside a class.

Comment: You are correct and I am humbled. There must be other errors with my code.

Comment: I stand corrected as well.  Deleting my answer so as not to misdirect other seekers.

Answer (score 2):

It should work as long as you've defined the constants before `AuthClass()` runs. If they are not in the same file as your `Auth` class, you will first need to include them within the file that `Auth` resides in so it can see them:

```
include("the_file_that_has_those_constants_in_it.php");
```

Then it should just work. Constants are already global so there is no need to use the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your constants aren't being defined before you instantiate class `Auth`.  When you use an undefined constant this way, PHP will issue a warning and convert it to a string.  If the problem is indeed that your constants aren't defined, your code will effectively be interpreted as:

```
$this->db_link = mysql_connect('DB_HOSTNAME', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD');
```

Given the error you're getting (**Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOSTNAME'**), I'm assuming this is what's happening.

As other answers state, make sure you're defining the constants before you attempt to call `Auth::AuthClass`.  If the class and the DB_* constants are defined in different files, make sure that both files are included before you attempt to instantiate/use class `Auth`.

---

As an aside, defined constants are *not* variables.  You cannot use `global CONSTANT_NAME;` in this way, and you do not need to - all constants are always global, and available everywhere after the point they're defined.  A simple test proves this:

```
define ('MY_CONST', 3);

class Test {
    function __construct() { echo MY_CONST; }
}

$x = new Test(); // outputs 3
```